# Example of $C^{1,\alpha}$ domain not satisfying the interior sphere condition

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I would like to prove there exists $C^{1,\alpha}$ with $0<\alpha<1$  not satisfying the  interior Sphere condition.
I consider $\Omega=\{(,)\in \Bbb R^2:>||^{1+\alpha}\},$ with $0<\alpha<1$. This domain is $C^{1\alpha}$ smooth. From the graph of $y=|x|^{1+\alpha}$ I can see that $(0,0)\in \partial \Omega$ does not satisfies the interior sphere condition.

How can I prove this formally?

**Recall Definition:**
A point $a\in \partial \Omega$ satisfies the interior sphere condition for $\Omega$ if  there exists a ball $B,$ $B\subset \Omega$ such that $\partial \Omega\cap \partial B=\{a\}$.

Comment: Since a circle tangent to the $x$-axis at the origin lies above some parabola $y = kx^2$, it suffices to prove no such parabola lies above the boundary.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang this seems to be an incorrect conclusion to me. If you know the circle lies above the parabola, how does it help if you know the parabola cannot lie above the graph of the function? If you want to show the circle is below the graph by help of the parabola, you need the circle to be below the parabola.

Comment: @Thomas You're perfectly correct; brain lapse on my part. (For OP, the suggestion is to replace a circle with a simpler graph whose asymptotic behavior can be compared directly to the boundary of your example.)